# Can you use tsc to type check multiple typescript projects at once without building them?

Tags: typescript, typechecking, tsconfig, tsc

In theory, you should be able to do this by using [references](https://www.staging-typescript.org/tsconfig#references) to make a top-level tsconfig file that includes paths to all of the different typescript projects you want to check, setting `"composite": true` on the `tsconfig.json` files for each individual project, and then running `tsc --project top_level_tsconfig.json --noEmit`.

For example, `top_level_tsconfig.json` could look like this:

```
{
    "references": [
    {
      "path": "./project1/tsconfig.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./project2/tsconfig.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

Running `tsc --project top_level_tsconfig.json --noEmit` with that setup just gets a bunch of `somefile.d.ts has not been built from source file somefile.ts` errors, though. [This thread](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40431) talks about why that happens.

`tsc --project project1/tsconfig.json --noEmit` and `tsc --project project2/tsconfig.json --noEmit` run just fine, as long as you turn off the `"composite": true` option, but you can't turn off `"composite": true` when using the `references` option. [This thread](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36917) talks about this, but none of the provided solutions seem to help for this case, and there doesn't seem to be any other way to typecheck multiple projects at once with `--noEmit`.

I know you can use tools like `concurrently` to just run `tsc` a bunch of times concurrently, but it would be nice to be able to do this with just `tsc` if possible. Is there a way?

Comment: I'm trying to find an answer to this as well but I don't think it's possible right now, even almost 2 years later.